# Is etherDElta exchange decentralized or semi-decentralized?

Tags: decentralization, etherdelta

Is etherDelta truely decentralized that lives on the blockchain itself or is it prone to a single point of failure? Obviously the website itself is centralized, but what if I wanted to fire up my own local instance of etherdelta to interact with the decentralized exchange. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

EtherDelta does seem to be [a completely decentralised exchange](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/6hrwnu/etherdelta_is_a_decentralized_exchange/) - baring as you rightfully point out the UI.

> If I wanted to fire up my own local instance of etherdelta to interact with the decentralized exchange. Is this possible and how?

Rather than firing up an instance of EtherDelta in order to interact with the exchange, I think instead you would interact directly with this, exchange, [smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code).

EtherDelta have written up quite a detailed document giving [an overview of the exchange smart contract](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/6kdiyl/smart_contract_overview/).

Comment: So I have to write up my own UI to interact with the smart contract. There isn't a pre-built interface yet im assuming.